# Is it possible to run http.ListenAndServe() AND ReadFromUDP() concurrently?

Tags: http, go, udp

I am trying to write a simple web app that will listen for UDP packets.

But I can either only listen for UDP packets, or run the web app... 
I am not familiar with GoLang, but here's the code I'm using to...
listen for UDP:

```
 ServerConn, _ := net.ListenUDP("udp", &net.UDPAddr{IP:[]byte{#,#,#,#},Port:####,Zone:""})
  defer ServerConn.Close()
  buf := make([]byte, 1024)

  for {
    n, addr, _ := ServerConn.ReadFromUDP(buf)
    fmt.Println("Received ", string(buf[0:n]), " from ", addr)
  }
```

Server logic:

```
    package main
We import 4 important libraries 
1. “net/http” to access the core go http functionality
2. “fmt” for formatting our text
3. “html/template” a library that allows us to interact with our html file.
4. "time" - a library for working with date and time.
import (
   "net/http"
   "fmt"
   "time"
   "html/template"
)

//Create a struct that holds information to be displayed in our HTML file
type Welcome struct {
   Name string
   Time string
}

//Go application entrypoint
func main() {
   //Instantiate a Welcome struct object and pass in some random information. 
   //We shall get the name of the user as a query parameter from the URL
   welcome := Welcome{"Anonymous", time.Now().Format(time.Stamp)}

   //We tell Go exactly where we can find our html file. We ask Go to parse the html file (Notice
   // the relative path). We wrap it in a call to template.Must() which handles any errors and halts if there are fatal errors

   templates := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/welcome-template.html"))

   //Our HTML comes with CSS that go needs to provide when we run the app. Here we tell go to create
   // a handle that looks in the static directory, go then uses the "/static/" as a url that our
   //html can refer to when looking for our css and other files. 

   http.Handle("/static/", //final url can be anything
      http.StripPrefix("/static/",
         http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))) //Go looks in the relative "static" directory first using http.FileServer(), then matches it to a
         //url of our choice as shown in http.Handle("/static/"). This url is what we need when referencing our css files
         //once the server begins. Our html code would therefore be <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/static/stylesheet/...">
         //It is important to note the url in http.Handle can be whatever we like, so long as we are consistent.

   //This method takes in the URL path "/" and a function that takes in a response writer, and a http request.
   http.HandleFunc("/" , func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

      //Takes the name from the URL query e.g ?name=Martin, will set welcome.Name = Martin.
      if name := r.FormValue("name"); name != "" {
         welcome.Name = name;
      }
      //If errors show an internal server error message
      //I also pass the welcome struct to the welcome-template.html file.
      if err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "welcome-template.html", welcome); err != nil {
         http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
      }
   })

   //Start the web server, set the port to listen to 8080. Without a path it assumes localhost
   //Print any errors from starting the webserver using fmt
   fmt.Println("Listening");
   fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil));
}
```

taken from(https://medium.com/google-cloud/building-a-go-web-app-from-scratch-to-deploying-on-google-cloud-part-1-building-a-simple-go-aee452a2e654)

I tried putting both of these extracts in 1 file, as well as running 2 files at the same time using

```
go run *.go
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Run one of the listeners in a goroutine.  See related questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271156/listen-to-2-ports-on-1-server), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749579/can-i-setup-multi-port-from-one-web-app-with-go).

Comment: @CeriseLimón i did it, but now I'm getting `http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from main.main.func1`, even thought i never call WriteHeader myself

Comment: The calls to `templates.ExecuteTemplate` and `http.Error` call `WriteHeader` indirectly.  Log the error returned from  `templates.ExecuteTemplate` and fix whatever error is reported.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to start looking into goroutines - since you're asking to do two things concurrently. I suggest doing some reading into channels, goroutines, and concurrency in general :)